# Matlab keep crashing when building an interest rate tree. Any advice?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, finance

I am trying to build an interest rate tree (a binomial tree type figure used to value bonds). I have been following along this page:https://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/hjmtree.html

When running my code, matlab exits with the following warning "Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. The original names are saved in the VariableDescriptions property. "

Do you have any idea what I can do to make that work?

Different methods for doing the trees; transposing yield matrices.

```matlab
%import excel
yields = readtable('YIELDS.csv');

%assign var to each columns
time=yields.time;
yield=yields.spotYield/100;

startdate=['01-Jan-2019'; '01-Jan-2020'; '01-Jan-2021'; '01-Jan-2022'; '01-Jan-2023'; '01-Jan-2024'; '01-Jan-2025'; '01-Jan-2026'; '01-Jan-2027'; '01-Jan-2028'; '01-Jan-2029'; '01-Jan-2030'; '01-Jan-2031'; '01-Jan-2032'; '01-Jan-2033'; '01-Jan-2034'; '01-Jan-2035'; '01-Jan-2036'; '01-Jan-2037'; '01-Jan-2038'; '01-Jan-2039'; '01-Jan-2040'; '01-Jan-2041'; '01-Jan-2042'; '01-Jan-2043'; '01-Jan-2044'; '01-Jan-2045'; '01-Jan-2046'; '01-Jan-2047'; '01-Jan-2048'];
enddate=['01-Jan-2020'; '01-Jan-2021'; '01-Jan-2022'; '01-Jan-2023'; '01-Jan-2024'; '01-Jan-2025'; '01-Jan-2026'; '01-Jan-2027'; '01-Jan-2028'; '01-Jan-2029'; '01-Jan-2030'; '01-Jan-2031'; '01-Jan-2032'; '01-Jan-2033'; '01-Jan-2034'; '01-Jan-2035'; '01-Jan-2036'; '01-Jan-2037'; '01-Jan-2038'; '01-Jan-2039'; '01-Jan-2040'; '01-Jan-2041'; '01-Jan-2042'; '01-Jan-2043'; '01-Jan-2044'; '01-Jan-2045'; '01-Jan-2046'; '01-Jan-2047'; '01-Jan-2048'; '01-Jan-2049'];

forward=zero2fwd(yield,startdate,'01-Jan-2018');

vol=0.23;

VolSpec=hjmvolspec('Stationary', vol);
RateSpec=intenvset('Compounding', 1, 'ValuationDate','01-Jan-2019', 'StartDates',startdate, 'EndDates', enddate,'Rates', forward);
TimeSpec=hjmtimespec('01-Jan-2019',enddate,1);

HJMTree = hjmtree(VolSpec, RateSpec, TimeSpec);
treeviewer(HJMTree);
```

Comment: The warning message is just telling you that the column headers in `YIELDS.csv` are not valid MATLAB variable names and are automatically being converted to valid MATLAB variable names to use as column headers in the table being created by `readtable`.  That almost certainly has nothing to do with MATLAB crashing.  If you run your code one line at a time where does the crash occur?

Comment: Is there anything else happening despite the warning? Does the GUI of MATLAB freeze? Is there a crash report  popping up on your screen?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it gives me the message "MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to be closed".

Comment: And when I run it line by line it crashes at the HMJTree line. Also might be worth noting that when I replace "enddate" in the TimeSpec variable by a single date. It does not crash anymore but give me an error message.

Comment: Final comment, when I put less dates in my enddate and stardate list, it works fine. Do you think 30 dates is just too much for matlab to handle?

Comment: Please put the actual error message in your question.